# I got error saying '%yacc' and '%define api.value.type "union"' cannot be used together

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer, yacc

I am working on creating a simple compiler, I need to generate a Symantec value type, I have checked that [link](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Type-Generation.html), and I need to add this line in my parser.y file:

```
%define api.value.type union
```

to inform the bison that the tags used with the %token and %type directives are genuine types.

but I got that strange error:

> parser.y: error: '%yacc' and '%define api.value.type "union"'
>   cannot be used together

I don't understand what the "%yacc" variable and why got that error, as far as I understand, the '%define api.value.type "union"' I can use it inside the parser normally, and I can't find any information or resources about that error.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for that does not simply restate the error message? If you explain to us why you think you need the `%yacc` option, then maybe we can suggest a way around that.

Comment: as I said, I have no option called %yacc, I don't use such a variable in the code, and I don't think I need it, I guess that it belongs to the way I run the parser.y file, as I use the command `$ yacc -d parser.y` , but I am not sure if that the reason I got that error, and how to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted on [this page of the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Invocation.html#Invocation), bison includes a `yacc` front end that runs `bison -y`.  The `-y` option forces various yacc-compatibility settings as described [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Bison-Options.html#Bison-Options).

Hence, the solution is to run `bison` rather than `yacc`.